# Get the last tweet id with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to have the last tweet id of the user with Tweepy. This is my code :

```
_consumer_key = config.APP_KEY
_consumer_secret = config.APP_SECRET
_access_token = config.OAUTH_TOKEN
_access_secret = config.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(_consumer_key,_consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(_access_token, _access_secret)
client = tweepy.API(auth)
print('Connected as @{}, you can start to tweet !'.format(client.me().screen_name))
client_id = client.me().id
tweet = client.user_timeline(id = client_id, count = 1)[0]
print(tweet.id)

#tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': 'You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you�ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve', 'code': 453}]
```

I can't understand the error, How can I have the last tweet id  with tweepy

Answer (score 0):

You need to request for elevated access
go here, fill out the form: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/elevated

Comment: This link now redirects to: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products and the elevated access request form seems to have been removed.  Any new way?